# Dynamic substitution of variables in bash

Tags: bash

Honestly I don't even know how to ask this, or what are the proper terms lol

So what I'm trying to do, is to work on variables with variable names. I think I'd best describe it by actually showing it:
So what I had before was this

```
if [ -z ${file_var} ]; then
        echo "empty argument"
fi
if [ -z ${pw_var} ]; then
        echo "empty argument"
fi
```

So what I was trying to do was not have two if statements, but have just one and a for loop, something like this:

```
for i in file_var, pw_var;do
        if [ -z ${${i}} ]; then
                echo "empty argument"
        fi
done
```

Now this obviously doesn't work, so I'm wondering how is it properly done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is [*indirect expansion*, which Bash supports using `!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
if [ -z "${!i}" ] ; then
```

> If the first character of *parameter* is an exclamation point (`!`), and *parameter* is not a *nameref*, it introduces a level of indirection. Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of *parameter* as the new parameter; this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion, rather than the expansion of the original parameter. This is known as **indirect expansion**.

In this case, `"${!i}"` expands to whatever the value of the variable whose *name* is stored in `i`, and `-z` will test that indirectly-accessed value.

---

Alternatively, a *nameref* is a special type of variable that has this behaviour automatically. You [make a nameref variable using `declare -n name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare), and thereafter

> All references, assignments, and attribute modifications to `name`, except for those using or changing the `-n` attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by `name`’s value.

So if you add

```
declare -n i
```

before your loop, it will mean that just

```
for i in file_var pw_var
do
    if [ -z "$i" ]
    then
    ...
    fi
done
```

will work as you wanted. Do note though that *assignments* to `i` (as opposed to its being set in a loop like this) will modify the target variable.

---

Note also that there is no comma between items you're looping over in a Bash `for` loop like how you've written it in the question.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed! Also thanks for the for loop tip :D

Comment: Namerefs are not supported on some older bashes, so use them carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This code works, if file_var or pw_var are empty it will print that the specific variable is empty. You can tweak it to fit your usage.

```
file_var=""
pw_var=""

for i in 'file_var' 'pw_var';do
  if [ -z ${!i} ]; then
    echo "$i is empty"
  fi
done
```